# canvas上で文字色を透明にし、背景を透かしたい

Tags: javascript, canvas

以下のサンプル画像にあるように、文字の部分を透過して背景を透けるようにしたいです。
`globalCompositeOperation`を使ってみましたが、canvasそのものに作用してしまうようで、文字部分が白く透けてしまいます。

[図] こうしたい
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[図」こうなってしまう
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

`<canvas>`タグを`display:none;`にしてそこで文字を描画し、後から`canvas`同士を合成するような方法しかないでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

背景画像、文字抜きの青四角ともに一つの`<canvas>`に描く必要があって、文字抜きの青四角を事前に準備できないのなら、2つ `<canvas>` が必要になりそうです。1つは `OffscreenCanvas` でよいですが。

もし、背景画像は CSS の `background-image` で描画してもいいなら1つの `<canvas>` でできると思います。

```js
const context = c.getContext('2d');
context.fillStyle = 'blue';
context.fillRect(10, 100, 280, 100);

context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
context.fillStyle = 'black';
context.font = '80px sans-serif';
context.fillText('あ', 120, 180);
```

```css
#c {
  background-image: url(https://placehold.jp/60/703e56/ffffff/300x300.png);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width=300 height=300>
</canvas>
```